# I get segmentation fault while making a simple pthreads program in C and I don't understand why

Tags: c

This simple code compiles fine but when I use `pthread_join(t1, NULL)` it returns segmentation fault (core dump)

```
int number = 0;

void* change_number(void *x){
    printf("helo from some thread\n");
        int num = *(int *)x;
        printf("%d\n", number);
        number += num;
    
        printf("a thread increased the variable by %d\n", num);
    }

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

        pthread_t t1;
        pthread_t t2;
        printf("1) SUccess code: %d\n", pthread_create(&t1, NULL, change_number, (void *) 5));
        printf("2) Success code: %d\n", pthread_create(&t2, NULL, change_number, (void *) 11));
        printf("%d\n",pthread_join(t1, NULL));
        printf("thread 1 finished\n");
        pthread_join(t2, NULL);

}
```

What is the issue here? I run this in a VM if it has any relevance

Comment: Where does the segfault occur?

Comment: `(void *) 5` pointer to address five. `*(int *)x` reads an int from address five (there isn't one). You could probably get away with `(int)x` although that's a mildly horrible way to deliver an int value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have noted, your problem is in `(void *) 5`, this is easily fixed:

```
int foo = 5, bar = 11;

printf("1) SUccess code: %d\n", pthread_create(&t1, NULL, change_number, (void *) &foo));
printf("2) Success code: %d\n", pthread_create(&t2, NULL, change_number, (void *) &bar));
```

As noted, you should make the `foo` and `bar` variables globals.

Comment: With a note that the variables should better be declared global (static?). Passing local variables to background threads is a bit of a loaded footgun. It would work with the code as written but might blow up on changes.

Answer (score 1):

`(void*)5` says to treat `5` *as* a pointer, where what you seem to want is a pointer to an `int` variable that *contains* 5.